# How do I set a shortcut to "Enable scrolling for outputs" in jupyter lab?

Tags: shortcut, jupyter-lab

How do I set a shortcut to "Enable scrolling for outputs" in jupyter lab?
So far, I found out how to set a shortcut. settings >> Advanced settings editor >> keyboard shortcuts.
But, on the list, I can't find any shortcuts for this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
    {
        "command": "notebook:enable-output-scrolling",
        "keys": ["S"],
        "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    },

    {
        "command": "notebook:disable-output-scrolling",
        "keys": ["Alt S"],
        "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
    }
```

Both seem to work fine for me for enabling and disabling output scrolling with jupyterlab 1.2.6.

Comment: I had issue "invalid json" could not save, as per https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/6865 the solution was to nest
```
{
       "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "notebook:enable-output-scrolling",
            "keys": [
                "S"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook:focus"
        }
    ]
}
```
(I also had file permissions errors when saving and solved with recursive `chown -R` on `~/.jupyter` folder. Also had to run `jupyter lab --generate-config` to create the file `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`)

Comment: Where shall I put it please?